# MS Access SQL query from 3 tables

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 3 tables shown below in MS Access 2010:

Table: **devices**

```
   id | device_id | Company | Version | Revision |
   -----------------------------------------------
   1  | dev_a     | Almaras | 1.5.1   | 0.2A     |
   2  | dev_b     | Enigma  | 1.5.1   | 0.2A     |
   3  | dev_c     | Almaras | 1.5.1   | 0.2C     |
*Field: device_id is Primary Key Unique String
*Field ID is just an auto-number column
```

**Table: activities**

```
   id | act_id | act_date   | act_type | act_note |
   ------------------------------------------------
    1 | dev_a  | 07/22/2013 | usb_axc  | ok       |
    2 | dev_a  | 07/23/2013 | usb_axe  | ok       | (LAST ROW for dev_a)
    3 | dev_c  | 07/22/2013 | usb_axc  | ok       | (LAST ROW for dev_c)
    4 | dev_b  | 07/21/2013 | usb_axc  | ok       | (LAST ROW for dev_b)
*Field: act_id contains device_id; NOT UNIQUE
*Field ID is just an auto-number column
```

**Table: matrix**

```
  id | mat_id | tc    | ts | bat | cycles |
  -----------------------------------------
  1  | dev_a  | 2811  | 10 | 99  | 200    |
  2  | dev_a  | 2911  | 10 | 97  | 400    |
  3  | dev_a  | 3007  | 10 | 94  | 600    |
  4  | dev_a  | 3210  | 10 | 92  | 800    | (LAST ROW for dev_d)
  5  | dev_b  | 1100  | 5  | 98  | 100    |
  6  | dev_b  | 1300  | 8  | 93  | 200    |
  7  | dev_b  | 1411  | 11 | 90  | 300    | (LAST ROW for dev_b)
  8  | dev_c  | 4000  | 27 | 77  | 478    | (LAST ROW for dev_c)
*Field: mat_id contains device_id; NOT UNIQUE
*Field ID is just an auto-number column
```

Is there any way to query tables to get results as shown below (each device from devices and only last row added [see example output table] from each of the other two tables):

**Query Results:**

```
device_id | Company | act_date   | act_type | bat | cycles |
------------------------------------------------------------
device_a  | Almaras | 07/23/2013 | usb_axe  |  92 |   800  |
device_b  | Enigma  | 07/21/2013 | usb_axc  |  90 |   300  |
device_c  | Almaras | 07/22/2013 | usb_axc  |  77 |   478  |
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance for reading and helping me out :)

Comment: Where you say 'last row from each of the other two tables' can you be a little more specific please. What is the ordering criteria?

Comment: Sorry about confusion. So each device from devices and last rows entered in tables matrix and activities. Regular joins won't work  :S

Comment: What exactly is meant by last row? If you mean last row in these examples then are we safe to assume that sorting each device by tc in matrix will give the correct order or should we use cycles or some other criteria? Also, what about Activities?

Comment: Last rows is the first from the bottom (last added in table for specific device_id); there is no sorting involved at all. Basically opposite of TOP 1 ...

Comment: It is not good practice to rely on databases returning rows in a specific order unless you are able to describe that order logically in an order by clause. This may work in MS Access, but does not in many RDBMS.

Comment: I got your point. However, the whole process has been designed by someone else. I will add some auto-number column now to remember hierarchy. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think is what you want,

```
SELECT  a.device_id, a.Company,
        b.act_date, b.act_type,
        c.bat, c.cycles
FROM    ((((devices AS a
        INNER JOIN activities AS b
            ON a.device_id = b.act_id)
        INNER JOIN matrix AS c
            ON  a.device_id = c.mat_id)
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  act_id, MAX(act_date) AS max_date
            FROM    activities
            GROUP   BY act_id
        ) AS d  ON b.act_id = d.act_id AND b.act_date = d.max_date)
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  mat_id, MAX(tc) AS max_tc
            FROM    matrix
            GROUP   BY mat_id
        ) AS e  ON c.mat_id = e.mat_id AND c.tc = e.max_tc)
```

The subqueries: `d` and `e` separately gets the latest row for every `act_id`.

Comment: You saved from spending additional tons of hours to figure it out.... OMG you are amazing; if I was there around you at this moment I would buy you a chocolate (huge one) :) Thank you; thank you!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT devices.device_id, devices.Company, activities.act_data, activities.act_type, matrix.bat, matrix.cycles
FROM devices
LEFT JOIN activities
ON devices.device_id = activities.act_id
LEFT JOIN matrix
ON devices.device_id = matrix.mat_id;
```

Comment: That would give me 10-20 rows for each device ... Please note that Device ID is not unique in matrix and activities tables ... I need only one row for each device. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you consider the "last" row in Matrix?

You need to do something like 
`WHERE act_date in (SELECT max(a.act_date) from activities a where a.mat_id=d.device_id GROUP BY a.mat_id)`

and something similar for the join to matrix.